# Let $V=span(\sin^2(x),\cos^2(x)$, and $T:V\to V$ by given by $T(f)=f''$. Determine if $T$ is one-to-one/onto

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, linear-transformations

Let $V=span(\sin^2(x),\cos^2(x)$, and $T:V\to V$ by given by $T(f)=f''$.

Determine if $T$ is one-to-one/onto

---

We know that any function $f$ can be represented by $r_1\sin^2(x)+r_2\cos^2(x)$.

$\ker{T}=\{f|f''=0\}$

$f=r_1\sin^2(x)+r_2\cos^2(x)$

$f''=2(r_1-r_2)(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))$

In order to have this equal $0$, we must have that $r_1=r_2$

Therefore, our $f$ must be of the form $r_1(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))=r_1(1)=r_1$

Therefore, a **basis** for the $\ker(T)$ = $\{1\}\neq 0$. Therefore not one-to-one.

---

How do I calculate the range$(T)$? I know range$(T)=span(\text{standard basis vectors})$, but what are the standard basis vectors in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range of $T$ can be obtained by the span of any basis vectors.

In particular $\{ \sin^2 x, -\cos^2 x\}$ is a basis.

Note that we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^2 x)= \frac{d}{dx}(1-\cos^2x)=\frac{d}{dx}(-\cos^2x)$$

Comment: So if we just set $e_1=\sin^2(x)$, then $T(e_1)=-\cos^2{x}$, but what does this tell me about it being onto ?

Comment: If we can show that $T(e_1)=T(e_2)$, what is the dimension of the range space?